# Cannot loop through web form Control in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a simple web form with some dropdown and textboxes. I am trying to get the value of the all the elements by looping through the control. (note I am assuming that I dont know the name/id of the elements and hence I am trying to loop through them to get the information and store it in a database) However the when I loop through control I get count at 5 even though there are 4 input elements and the control are represented by System.Web.UI.LiteralControl instead of System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox or System.Web.UI.WebControls.dropdown

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="Datepicker/jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Datepicker/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

     <script>
         $(function () {
             $("#targetDueDate").datepicker();
         });
  </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#targetdeliveryoffiles").datepicker();
        });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>Tier:

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="tier" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem>Select Tier</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Tier1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Tire2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Tier3</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Author: 

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="author" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem>Select Author</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Author1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Author2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Author3</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                      <tr>
                    <td>Quotation For:

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="quotationFor" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Previous Est #:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="previousEst" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
                            ControlToValidate="previousEst"
                            ValidationExpression="\d+"
                            Display="Dynamic"
                            EnableClientScript="true"
                            ErrorMessage="Please enter numbers only"
                            runat="server" ValidationGroup="a" ForeColor="Red" />
                    </td>
                </tr>


            </table>

            <br />

            <div style="text-align: center; width: 327px;">

                <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btnsubmit" ValidationGroup="a" OnClick="submit_Click" />

            </div>


        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The onsubmit code

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Control c in controls)
         {
            if(c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)
            {
                /// Do Something
            }
        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong ? How do I loop through the element to get their values ? (also the ID since I need to store both in the database)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is a control in web forms; static text is LiteralControl types.  So you need to check the type of control as you are and avoid Label, Literal, LiteralControl type of controls, and just look for the controls on your form.  Some controls are container controls, so you may need to get into recursion to get this to work.